# To show that the new update is available in app store

Tags: codenameone

In most of the app, I've seen that whenever the new update is available, it is shown in dialog box as soon as the app is opened. I think it is not a push notification since the notification msg doesn't appear in notification bar but only in a dialog box with remind me later, cancel go to appstore etc option when the app is opened.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common practice that doesn't necessarily use the store versioning support (often it doesn't). The app pings to a URL to check if it indicates a new version and notifies the user accordingly.

I intend to write a tip of the week about it in a couple of weeks.

Comment: Is there anything yet on this topic? I have not found anything till now.

Comment: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-cross-platform-update-available-strategy.html